How to create link to another part of document in Typst? The documentation is not quite helpful
I want to create an internal link to another section within the same document, but I don't have examples on how to do it

You are looking for the link function, note it can use a location as well:
MWE is this:
= Section 1 <my_anchor>

See #link(<my_anchor>)[here] or #link("https://google.com")[online].


If you want to be fancy, you can do something like this

#let link2(label, dest) = {
  link(dest)[#emph(underline(label))]
}

= Section 1 <my_anchor>

See #link2("here", <my_anchor>) or #link2("online", "https://google.com")

